# How to get the parameters of the method with value using mono.cecil?

Tags: .net, mono.cecil

Is it possible to get the values of method parameters using mono.cecil. I am doing interception of the method calls  let me know whether it is feasible?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, could you explain it a bit more and ideally also add an example and explain why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear what you mean but I'll try to answer.

`Cecil` can't help you in run-time, hence you can't evaluate value of parameter or any other run-time value.

But, with `Cecil` you can add code to `dll\exe` that can intercept any method call and in the interception code you can get the method parameters run-time values and to with them what you want.